# Google maps dragging doesn't work in lightbox

Tags: jquery, google-maps, z-index

I'm trying to show google maps inside lightbox but dragging and scrollwheel options doesn't work. Maybe you have idea what to do. I don't know if the problem is related with z-indexes. I tried everything.

So the lightbox what I am using is this: [Lightcase](http://www.cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/) . Its usless to put the whole lightbox code here, because I don't think you want to see it all here.

But some of my code what I can show:

```
Link:
<a data-rel="lightcase" href="#map-canvas2">Show map</a>

Div:
<div id="map-canvas2"></div>

Google maps JS code:
function initialize2() {

    var mapOptions2 = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.3491, 40.7159),
        disableDefaultUI: true
        draggable: true,
        scrollwheel: true
    }
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas2'), mapOptions2);
}

And some CSS:
#map-canvas2 {
    visibility: hidden;
    border: 0;
}
```

Width and height is given with JS. Visibility hidden is from this fix: [Map bug fix](http://www.matthewgifford.com/blog/2012/10/16/google-map-in-a-lightbox/), but these are not important. Just mentioned.

If I scroll when map is open, map zooming doesn't work, it is just scrolling page on the background.

Thank you if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library creates a clone of the container which will be displayed in the lightbox(which will not have any interactive functionality).

You may create a new Map-instance for the cloned node in the onFinish-callback, but I wouldn't suggest it, you better use another library, or modify this library so that it will use the original element instead of a clone.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Oh. I got it now. I found that in lightcase js (Clones the object for inline elements).

Comment: Solution: $('a[href^=#map-canvas2]').lightcase({onFinish:{resizeMap: function() {initialize2();}}});

Big thanks for Corner Boppart (author of plugin).